# How to specialize template function to distinguish void and non-void function arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I'd like to have 2 functions: accepting `void(*)(int)` and `int(*)(int)`.
How to write type_trait similar to std::is_invocable_r but checking exact return type (because any function can be cast to function returning void).

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
constexpr bool is_exact_invocable_r_v =
        std::is_same_v<R, std::invoke_result_t<C, Args...>>;
        // std::is_invocable_r_v<R, C, Args...>;

template<typename C, std::enable_if_t<is_exact_invocable_r_v<int, C>, int> = 0>
void print(C)
{
    printf("1\n");
}

template<typename C, std::enable_if_t<is_exact_invocable_r_v<int, C, int>, int> = 0>
void print(C)
{
    printf("2\n");
}

template<typename C, std::enable_if_t<is_exact_invocable_r_v<void, C, int>, int> = 0>
void print(C)
{
    printf("3\n");
}

int main()
{
    print([](){return 0;});
    print([](int){return 0;});
    print([](int){});
}
```

`std::is_invocable_r_v<R, C, Args...>` causes ambiguity because any type can be cast to void.

`std::is_same_v<R, std::invoke_result_t<C, Args...>>` causes substitution failure.

Comment: Just to clarify: `short(*)(int)` should match neither overload ? IOW, `std::is_same_v<decltype(C(0)), int>` ?

Comment: Also, `std::is_same_v` is not part of C++11

Comment: Please edit to add the exact error message you get from this program.

Comment: This has nothing to do with result being casted to void. The issue is that you are mixing the step of "is this a valid way to call my callable" and "what is the return type". The first step is SFINAE friendly, the second step is not. You need to conditionally check `invoke_result` only if `is_invokable` does not generate substitution failure.

Comment: Or stated differently, SFINAE can eliminate a declaration to cause a different specialization or overload to be used, but you just have the one template declaration, with no fallback to make the program legal if the `invoke_result_t` is illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is that your traits is ill formed when `C` is not callable with `Args...`, you have to SFINAE your variable:

```
template <typename R, typename C, typename TupleArgs, typename Enabler = void>
constexpr bool is_exact_invocable_r_v_impl = false;

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
constexpr bool is_exact_invocable_r_v_impl<R,
                                          C,
                                          std::tuple<Args...>,
                                          std::void_t<std::invoke_result_t<C, Args...>>> =
    std::is_same_v<R, std::invoke_result_t<C, Args...>>;

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
constexpr bool is_exact_invocable_r_v =
    is_exact_invocable_r_v_impl<R, C, std::tuple<Args...>>;
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6670d3d969d8d65)